# Substitution of variable into link with many interior quotes - how to escape correctly

Tags: javascript, variables, escaping, quotes

I am setting up a link to Adobe's Aviary web app, which requires input in the following format:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return launchEditor('editableimage1', 
'http://www.mywebsite.com/IMAGE.jpg');">Edit!</a>
```

I need to substitute a variable name for the IMAGE.jpg part of this, and I have tried to do this using the following code. Since the visual cues tell me that the variable name isn't being interpreted I already know this will fail, but I can't see how to express it properly.  Sorry, very new to Javascript so hope someone can kindly help.  Here's my code:

```
<script>
var imgNamePassed = sessionStorage.getItem('imgName');
console.log("imgName", imgNamePassed);
</script>

<a href='#' onclick="return launchEditor('editableimage1','http://www.mywebsite.com/ + imgNamePassed + "');&quot; />"LINK TEXT</a>
```

Comment: I found my main error was trying to set the text in the html and not in javascript. Changing in to onclick="myfunction()" and then performing the substitution and subsequent call in javascript worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it to:

```
<a href='#' onclick="return launchEditor('editableimage1','http://www.mywebsite.com/' + imgNamePassed);"/>LINK TEXT</a>
```

Example:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jmehdvd/)